# How does replacingCharacters work in a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm new to Swift and I'm learning about delegates:

```swift
class ZipCodeTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var newText = textField.text! as NSString
        newText = newText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString // this line

        return newText.length <= 5
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is basically a delegate to limit the character count to within 5.  But, I'm not quite sure what role this method `replacingCharacters` is playing in this function.  Apple documentation shows that it

> Returns a new string in which the characters in a specified range of
>   the receiver are replaced by a given string.

which seems pretty straight forward.  It replaces some range of characters with a replacement of your choice.  I can see that `textField` has a parameter called `range` and `replacementString`, but what range is being provided and what are they being replaced with?

The main `ViewController` that the delegate is being used in doesn't provide either of them. It simply instantiate the delegate and applies it to the relevant `textField`

```swift
    let zipCodeDelegate = ZipCodeTextFieldDelegate()

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    // MARK: Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.delegate = self.zipCodeDelegate

    }
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs for `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield)?

Comment: it says that `textField` is called every time the user causes it texts to change. It passes the same two parameters as replacingCharacters plus `textField`.  Shouldn't the `range` and the 'replacement' be passed still? Or is it by default subjecting to the entire texts within `textField` to be manipulated?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was away for awhile. I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you ask "shouldn't the range and the replacement be passed still?". Because yes, the range for the currently selected text is always passed to the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method, and the replacement string is always passed in as well. As far as the `replacingCharacters` function, all that's doing is taking the current text in the textfield and replacing the range of text with the replacement string to see what the new string _would_ be if you were to return true from that method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that the all texts in the textField get replaced with itself? In other words, does the range indicate the beginning character of the texts to the end character and the replacement the same texts from the textField? I'm not sure what "taking the current text in the textfield and replacing the range of text with the replacement string to see what the new string would be" means and what the purpose of it is.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yes, the `range` parameter means the range _within_ the current text of the textfield. So let's say the text in the textfield is "Hello world!" and the user selected "world", then hit the "A" key on the keyboard – then `shouldChangeCharactersIn` would get called, and `range` would be equal to `NSRange(location: 6, length: 5)` (because the location of "w" is at index 6 of the whole string, and the length of the selected text is 5, because `"world"` has 5 characters) and `replacementString` would be `"A"`.

Comment: Then, `replacingCharacters` is used on a local variable (a copy of the current textfield's text) to obtain what the new text would be if you were to return true from this delegate method. The point of doing that is to see if the new text length would be less than or equal to 5. And if that's true, then `true` is returned and the textfield allows the string replacement to happen. If `false` is returned, then the textfield's text is not changed.

Comment: (Sorry, "current textfield's text" is confusing – I meant "current text of the textfield".)

Comment: The above example is showing that even if the user is simply typing "Hello world!" without selecting anything, some sort of `range` and `replacementString` is being provided to `replacingCharacters`. Is this because as the sentence is being typed, "H" is being replaced with "He", "He" with "Hel", "Hel" with "Hello"? I guess I'm trying to figure out why do the texts have to get replaced when the length is being measured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212519/discussion-between-tylerthecompiler-and-kevvv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should understand the purpose of `shouldChangeCharactersIn`. Whenever the user tries to change the text of a text field in some way, the text field asks its delegates whether it "should change the characters", i.e. whether it should allow the user to do the change that they are trying to do.

Note that the user can change the textfield's text in a lot of ways, not just by "entering a single character". Here's a list of possible ways (you might be able to think of others):

1. entering a single character, or pasting some text
2. deleting a single character
3. selecting a range of characters, and deleting it
4. selecting a range of characters, and entering a single character, or pasting some text. This will replace the selected range with the single character, or pasted text

Notice that all those ways are just special cases of Way 4. In all of these ways, you are just replacing a range in the textfield's text with some new text. Let me reword the first 3 ways:

1. replacing a zero-length range at some position with a single character, or some pasted text
2. replacing a one-length range of the textfield with an empty string
3. replacing some range of the textfield with an empty string

When the user tries to change the textfield's text in any way, the textfield will make a call like similar to this:

```
delegate?.textField(self, shouldChangeCharactersIn: someRange, replacementString: someString)
```

You should now understand what the parameters `someRange` and `someString` are for. No matter how the user changes the text, it can always be modelled as "replacing a range of text (`someRange`) with some other text (`someString`)".

So what does

```
newText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

do?

It simply does the replacement mentioned before. Recall that this delegate method is the textfield asking you, "should this change (modelled as a range and a replacement string) be allowed?" And to determine that, you try to *do the change* first. If after the change, the text field's text has a length of at most 5, then it is allowed.

The line *tries to do the change*.

Of course, you are not changing the textfield's text when doing this change, which is why you assign it to a variable called `newText`.