# What main difference textFieldDidChange and shouldChangeCharactersIn method, the delegate of UITextFieldDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextviewdelegate

Can someone explain about when to use and how difference of them ?.

Comment: What is `textFieldDidChange`? There's no such thing in `UITextFieldDelegate`. There's only `textFieldDidChangeSelection`. Did you confuse it with something else? For `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, see [my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433592/how-does-replacingcharacters-work-in-a-delegate/64154028#64154028) in the context of limiting the number of characters in the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Simple words `textDidChange` occurs when any text is typed in Textfield and you want to get text typed on `TextField` to check for validation or anything...

```
func textDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty, email.isValidEmail() else {
            //Write your code here...
            return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty else {
            //Write your code here..
            return }
        //Write your success code. 
    }
```

And `shouldChangeCharactersIn` occurs event before any typed key is about to print in Textfield. So that you can varify that key and allow or restrict that key.
**Eg**: If user enter space in Password Textfield you can restrict that key and space will never is printed in Textfield.

In below code I am restricting space(" ") key in My Textfields.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
           if range.location == 0 && string == " " {
               return false
           }
           return true
       }
```