# How to enable addButton when corresponding textField has 3+ characters typed in?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfielddelegate

I have a textField and a submit button. The submit button is disabled by default and should only be enabled if textField has 3+ characters typed into it.

My code:

```
class AddNameVC: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addNameTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToAllNames", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        addNameTF.delegate = self
        addButton.isEnabled = false
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            addButton.isEnabled = addNameTF.text!.count > 2
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

After typing 3+ characters into the textField, button remains disabled. In fact, it never turns enabled no matter how many characters I type in.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method is *inside* of `viewDidLoad`. This means it doesn't actually implement the delegate method that you want to implement. You should move it outside, at the same level as `viewDidLoad`.

Also, because of [how `shouldChangeCharactersIn` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64154028/5133585), the text field's `text` has not been updated with the new text when it is called. You should instead compute the new text and use *that* to determine whether to enable the button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    addButton.isEnabled = newText.count > 2
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I learned that func should be outside of the viewdidload =)

Answer (score 0):

Put shouldChangeCharactersIn function outside of viewDidLoad, and check in it if character are > 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    addNameTF.delegate = self
    addButton.isEnabled = false
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.text?.count ?? 0 >= 2 {
        print("textfield = 3 charachters")
        addButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    return true
}
```